# Spring Thymeleaf collapse table with th:id

Tags: spring, twitter-bootstrap-3, thymeleaf

I'm trying to make each table entry have a hidden row that can be expanded/collapsed, so I tried to assign `th:id` using iteration but this doesn't seem to be working. Everything is generated but the hidden row doesn't expand when the button is pressed.

Any idea why? Or are there any other solutions/workaround?

```
<tbody th:each="topic, iterStat : ${topics}">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button data-toggle="collapse" data-th-target="'#demo' + ${iterStat.count}"> +</button>
        </td>
        <td th:text="${topic.getId()}"></td>
        <td th:text="${topic.getName()}"></td>
        <td th:text="${topic.getDescription()}"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6" class="hiddenRow">
            <div class="accordian-body collapse" th:id="'demo' + ${iterStat.count}"> Lorem ipsum</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: @Salman I didn't use any js for this aside from bootstrap.min.js. There are no errors.

Comment: What does it do `${iterStat.count}`?

Comment: @Salman The loop supposed to increment the iterStat.count each time, so iterStat is sort of like a counter.

Comment: you shouldn't make it like this. i would add my answer

Comment: Thymeleaf provides a variable which we can use while iterating using `th:each` and that has different properties like `count`, `index`. Safe to use when we need a dynamic ID. More about it [here](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#keeping-iteration-status)

Comment: @MohamedSanaulla that's where I got the idea to set unique IDs for all table rows so that they can be expanded individually without using js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `data-th-target="'#demo' + ${iterStat.count}"` will not work. Any custom attributes in Thymeleaf need to be defined as: `th:attr="data-th-target=|#demo${iterStat.count}|"`

Update:

The attribute should be `data-target` and not `data-th-target`

Comment: I tried different variations of the same thing but it still doesn't work...

Comment: And its only `data-target` and not `data-th-target` look at the [docs ](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse)

Comment: Thanks, I sort of got it to work after changing it to `th:attr="data-target=${topic.getId()}"` and so on accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error but solved it with this.

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample"
                            th:each="todo : ${todos}">
                            <div class="accordion-item">
                                <h2 class="accordion-header" th:id="heading + ${todo.id}">
                                    <button class="accordion-button" type="button"
                                        data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                                        th:attr="data-bs-target=|#col${todo.id}" aria-expanded="true"
                                        aria-controls="collapseOne">Accordion Item #1</button>
                                </h2>
                                <div th:id="col + ${todo.id}"
                                    class="accordion-collapse collapse show"
                                    th:attr="aria-labelledby=|heading${todo.id}|"
                                    data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                                    <div class="accordion-body">
                                        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It
                                        is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the
                                        appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These
                                        classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing
                                        and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this
                                        with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also
                                        worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the
                                        <code>.accordion-body</code>
                                        , though the transition does limit overflow.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```